# Phantom Workflow

Tags: workflow-activity

I created a new site with a new site collection. However I did bring over a custom list from another site. Now when I create new items a workflow fires. The strange thing is, in workflow settings on the site, list and SPD there are no workflows listed. Thanks in advance for any ideas where this rouge workflow could be hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely try to open this list up in SharePoint Designer and see if there are any workflows activated. Also, you can try to see if there are any workflows attached to the content type of the list. It also may be a custom feature workflow, so I would try to see if there are any custom features enabled on that site collection.

Comment: Found it. That little bugger was hiding on a workflow tied to Item creation in that list. Thanks

Comment: @Greg, please post that as an answer to get this question in a resolved state